# It comes and goes just like (the) tide

Tags: articles, definite-article

1.

> A. It comes and goes, just like tide.
>
> B. It comes and goes, just like the tide.

2.

> A. It is small, just like sand.
>
> B. It is small, just like the sand.

3.

> A. It is pretty, just like coral.
>
> B. It is pretty, just like the coral.

Which forms are correct for each sentences, which are comments you would make unconsciously without any references?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With ***sand*** and ***coral***, it's simply a matter of whether you're talking about the *substance in general*, or some specific example of it that has already been mentioned (or is contextually obvious).

With ***tide***, the article is *always* included, even though it doesn't refer to anything specific. People are always talking about things that [come and go](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22come%20and%20go%20like%20the%20tide%22) or [rise and fall](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22rise%20and%20fall%20like%20the%20tide%22) like the tide. Everyone knows those are things tides do, so we don't need any *particular* tide for comparison.

If there are any general principles governing whether the article is *optional, required,* or *invalid/unlikely*, and whether including it makes any difference to the *meaning*, I'm not consciously aware of them.

> 1: *God's presence released upon us is like [the] **rain** that falls upon the earth* [(Source)](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22like%20the%20rain%20that%20falls%20upon%22#tbm=bks&q=%22like%20the%20rain%20that%20falls%20upon%20the%20earth%22)
>    2: *May he be like [the] **rain** that falls on mown grass* [(Source)](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22like%20rain%20that%20falls%20on%20mown%22)

As it happens, #1 includes the article and #2 doesn't. But I can't see it would make any difference if that position were reversed. I'm sure I could think up further examples where the article either *does* affect meaning, or doesn't work, at all. But I don't think there's any obvious pattern to such usages - you just have to get used to them one by one.